# Click button in table and redirect to same page

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I have a view:

```
class ProductList(SingleTableView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "app/product_list.html"
    table_class = ProductTable
```

where in every row there is a button that should perform `function()`:

```
class ButtonColumn(tables2.Column):
    empty_values = list() 
    def render(self, value, record): 
        return mark_safe(f"""<a href="/link/{record.id}/"><button class="btn btn-info">link</button></a>""")
```

this `ButtonColumn` provides a button and once it is clicked:

```
    path("link/<int:pk>", views.LinkView.as_view(), name="link"),
```

And the corresponding view:

```
class LinkView(TemplateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "app/product_list.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('product-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        function[kwargs] # <------------------
        context["table"] = Product.objects.all()
        return(context)
```

My problem is with the Linkview - I want it to perform `function` with some URL transmitted paramters and return to the former page (`app/product_list.html`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `ButtonColumn` like this

```py
class ButtonColumn(tables2.Column):
    empty_values = list() 
    def render(self, value, record): 
        return mark_safe(f"""<a href="/link/{record.id}/?price=10"><button class="btn btn-info">link</button></a>""")
# There is no need to mention these query parameter in path.
```

The path will remain the same. **No need to change anything**.

```py
    path("link/<int:pk>", views.LinkView.as_view(), name="link"),
```

In you `ListView`, you would use `self.request.GET.get("param1", "")` where `param1` is the URL transmitted parameter and `""` is the default value.

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        param1 = self.request.GET.get("param1", "")
        # OR
        function(self.request.GET) # extract required params in the function
        function[kwargs] # <------------------
        context["table"] = Product.objects.all()
        return(context)
```

Note: **Get** is a dictionary

To redirect,

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirects

# In your LinkView override get method
class LinkView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect('some/url')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion using this urls.py entry: `path(r"link/(<int:pk>/(?P<price>[0-9]+)$", views.Linkiew.as_view(), name="link")` which leads to `404: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/30/?price=10`. Also how is your suggest redirecting me to my previous view (`app/product_list.html`)?

Comment: There is no need to add the query parameter `price` in the path. Just pass them in the url and access the parameter in the view. As for redirect, from the code, I understand that user is already on the `LinkView` and there is no need to redirect the user anywhere.

Comment: The user is on `ProductListView` where he clicks the button, which performs a function via `LinkView` but he should end up back on `ProductListView`.

Comment: To redirect, you will need to override the `get` method of `LinkView`.